# KUSTO WILDCARD character to Trim or Replace

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, appinsights

I am looking for a wild card character which could be used to trim or replace a matching string in KUSTO.

A simple example:

let string_to_trim = @"https://bing.com";
let substring = ".com"; // **---> Need a wildcard to use like let substring = ".{wildcard char}";**

print string_to_trim = string_to_trim, trimmed_string = trim(substring,string_to_trim)

Result: https://bing

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for the [parse operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator)

for example:

```
datatable(url:string)["https://bing.com"]
| parse url with Domain "." Extension
```